# What are the differences between Perseus and Adam kernels

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, kernel

I have a Galaxy S4 i9500 and have started looking into Android development and custom ROMS to get a feel on how they are made, what changes they provide and to what they focus on. But I always end up with one question that has gone unanswered at least to my full understanding.

Whats is the difference between the Stock kernel (The one that comes in 4.2 or 4.3) and the Perseus and adam Kernels.

It terms of CPU usage, RAM usage, speed and Battery usage, in what do they differ. What do they offer that the stock or other versions do not?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Different devices have different kernels so it's important to list your device (I've edited your question to include it for you). [Your other post](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56179/which-baseband-version-is-the-official-one-for-the-4-3) indicates that you have a Galaxy S4. I don't think the question is off-topic, but you're more likely to get a faster answer from the [XDA Developers Galaxy S4 subforum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=2162). I'd be surprised if anyone here was familiar with this kind of information.

Comment: Thank you dotVezz for the kind words. Will follow on your advice.